# Linked inbox stuck on synchronising google mail

Tags: 8.0, email, nokia-lumia-920, linked-accounts

After having set up a linked inbox and it worked, I occasionally have problems where after clicking the tile to access the linked inbox **the application seems to be stuck on trying to sync with my gmail**. Other linked accounts are my `microsoft live` account.

The top of the application reads `Google Mail - Synchronising...` and the rest of the screen is empty except for the settings bar at the bottom. No matter how long I wait, the synchronization does never finish. I have tried restarting the phone as well as turning flight mode on and off again, which sometimes seems to fix the problem.

Is there any setting that could be wrong that makes the synchronization fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [bug](http://www.wpcentral.com/severe-windows-phone-8-bug-rears-its-head-gmail-users) in Windows Phone 8 and Gmail. A suggested solution is to use POP:

> On Windows Phone 8 when you set up a Google Mail account you are
>   offered two options: ‘Email only’ or ‘Email, contacts and calendar’.
>   That latter option is the push-IMAP2 version while ‘Email only’ is POP
>   and will give you just 15-minute sync periods.

There are also some [other](http://www.wpcentral.com/severe-windows-phone-8-bug-rears-its-head-gmail-users) suggestions, but unfortunately POP might be your only option since Google is [dropping](http://www.theverge.com/2012/12/14/3768274/google-gmail-activesync-windows-phone) ActiveSync    support on January 30th 2013.

Comment: If you enable ActiveSync on this device before Google stops support then it will still be enable, just won't be able to add new devices