# Linked Inbox tile's number of new messages stuck

Tags: 8.0, email, nokia-lumia-920, tiles, linked-accounts

A [previous question of mine](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/linked-inbox-stuck-on-synchronising-google-mail) was about buggy synchronization of emails in a linked inbox on windows phone 8 running on a Lumia 920.

Now I sort of got the synchronization working by tweaking with the sync settings of contacts for those accounts, but there is one thing that still seems buggy.

The number of new inbox items seems stuck at `3`, for whatever odd reason. The number has not changed over the last few days, even though inbox items and unread inbox items changed a lot. The same on the lock screen - it always shows 3 unread items, no matter what the real count.

Am I missing something here or is this part of the, euhmm, let's call it, *general flux of bugginess* in wp8's linked account managment?

Comment: Do you have some folders in which you get your mail but you don't see them in the feed. You have to hit the `...` and then go to folders... maybe there are some emails

Comment: I do have folders, namely both for hotmail and for google mail there are `inbox`, `sent` and `show all folders` "folders". The last has about 20 subfolders on my google mail, and some 3 or so subfolder for the hotmail account. Nevertheless, I don't see any unread mail in *any* of those.

Comment: Does rebooting the phone fix the issue?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I am confident I must have tried rebooting. I am, however, not actively using the phone any more, so I can't confirm.

Comment: Have turned that into a loose answer, as it may help future visitors who have the issue, and find your question

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something [similar happen on phones running 7.x](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1643/106), if the mail sync crashed. A simple reboot was enough to fix it then, and I've not experienced the problem since moving to Windows Phone 8.0