# Is it possible to abort email synchronisation?

Tags: sync, email

It appears that recently email synchronisation is hanging "quite regularly" (at least daily) - this leaves the notification on the lock screen, but stops all the email accounts (Windows Live, Google, Outlook (i.e. Exchange) and two POP3 accounts) from downloading new messages.

At first I thought this might be because I was reading my gmail using the Windows 8 mail client on my laptop, but it is now being seen to happen when my laptop is asleep.

It appears the only way to get any notifications working again is to reboot the phone, which is slightly annoying, as it loses the information on the currently playing album/track.

Is there any way to find out the cause of the hang, or is there any mechanism to abort/retry the synchronisation? (even better if it could report the crash to Microsoft)

Comment: If you switch on flight mode, anything that is currently syncing will fail and marked as "not up to date" in the settings page. Can't comment on why it's happening in the first place though.

Comment: @rikkit I've had it crash synchronising an Exchange account, flipped flight mode on, and the email is still synchronising, according to the mail app (and I suspect it will now be hung until I reboot the phone).

Comment: Weird, sounds like an actual bug (rather than low connectivity like I thought!). You should report it to Nokia/ HTC (or whoever made your phone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been resolved in Windows Phone 8, but there remains no method to abort synchronisation

Comment: ...seemed to work so far... I have the same problem, the account stuck in syncing mode and there is no way I can stop it. Even reboot doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can resynchronize by opening the appropriate inbox and pressing "sync" in the app bar.

To cancel automatic synchronization, simply go to the settings and then turn of automatic synchronization for your e-mail account.

Comment: You cannot edit synchronisation settings during a sync though?

Comment: No, but do it Before sync then

Comment: My problem is that it *sometimes* crashes whilst syncing - not syncing gives the same result of it crashing, but without being able to check mail at all, so surely this would leave me worse off?

Comment: What account is causing the crashes?

Comment: How would I be able to tell? All five just say "synchronising" when I've noticed it's hung.

Comment: 1. Turn of sunchronization for all accounts.
2. Synchronize one account per time.
3. Once Everything hangs, you know what account is causing the issue.
4. Tell me what account is causing the hang

Comment: @RowlandShaw???

Comment: I've had it hang with Exchange, GMail, and POP3 accounts. Even turning on "flight mode" doesn't get the mail app to stop "synchronising". Only a reboot stops it