# Sync not working, can’t send or receive emails or texts, what could be the reason?

Tags: 8.0, htc-8x

Since last two days I am facing this issue in HTC 8X, please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1643/106

Comment: Is the possible duplicate help you? Did you think your question is really different from that? In case of "yes" please improve your question.

Comment: @RowlandShaw the possible duplicate doesn't seem relevant to this question. Though I agree that this question isn't that great.

Comment: @NeeleshPandey It sounds like you don't have a connection to your mobile network. Can you receive phone calls? Can you browse the internet on your phone?

Comment: @rikkit Same symptoms though; The phone appears to be all OK, able to make and receive calls, Internet access works in IE, but the email screen sits at "Synchronising ." and it doesn't update; sending SMSes appears to queued somewhere, and the "me" live tile doesn't update. In my experience rebooting the phone appears to resolve the issue for the short term

Comment: @NeeleshPandey, how is it going for you? Are you able to sync yet?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar issues on a Lumia 1520 device.
Make sure that the date and time is set correctly. Some devices apparently have issues maintaining a synchronized clock when their battery depletes.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you phone has background data enabled.

Check to see that your phone is not blocking background data to your email service.

Check to make sure the phone loads fewer messages and that it loads in shorter intervals.

If none of those things are work check to make sure that your email is not blocking messages from being set to your device.

I know gmail will sometimes not authorize your device sighting security issues.

Comment: Would be great if u could add how to do these thing. Or atleast a link which has some instructions